# xslt mapping transformation - node filtering

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an issue with creating a xslt condition to have a node filter up to the latest job information.

below xml input

```
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
  <CompoundEmployee>
    <id>11111</id>
    <person>
      <employment_information>
        <job_information>
          <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
          <start_date>2017-05-17</start_date>
        </job_information>
        <job_information>
          <end_date>2018-12-31</end_date>
          <start_date>2017-05-17</start_date>
        </job_information>
      </employment_information>
    </person>
  </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

here is xml output I would like to have

```
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
  <CompoundEmployee>
    <id>11111</id>
    <person>
      <employment_information>
        <job_information>
          <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
          <start_date>2017-05-17</start_date>
        </job_information>
      </employment_information>
    </person>
  </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

here is xslt input

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>


<!--remove all employees with past and previous dalta to have only current data-->

 <xsl:template match="//queryCompoundEmployeeResponse/CompoundEmployee/person/employment_information/job_information[((start_date &lt; current-date()) and (job_information/end_date &gt; current-date()))]"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Rule is simple that the latest job_information node is always at the most top of xml and I would like to have only the latest job_information in whole xml input.

It works fine with xpath filter:

```
/queryCompoundEmployeeResponse/CompoundEmployee[(person/employment_information/job_information[1])]
```

but I need to have above xpath condition inside the xslt condition regarding start_date and end_date.

Can you help me?

Comment: Your sample makes no sense. Both `job_information` have a `start_date` in the past and an `end_date` in the future. Which one should be kept, and why? Also, please remove all the irrelevant bits from the XML. 95% of the elements in your sample have no relation to your question whatsoever - remove everything that is not directly necessary, and add the expected output for that reduced sample.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, corrected the question

Comment: Please edit the XML input: there is a closing </job_information> without matching opening tag <job_information>.

Comment: corrected the input, thank you

Comment: BTW, the "code snippet" feature is mainly targeted at interactive, runnable demos for CSS, HTML and JavaScript. It does not make a lot of sense for XSLT.

Comment: Tell me what is better way to show xslt?

Comment: Just a regular code block - indented by four spaces, the way it currently is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template should match any `<job_information>` that has an end date in the past.

```
<xsl:template match="job_information[xs:date(end_date) &lt; current-date()]" />
```

I think it's not necessary to make it any more complex than this.

Note that it's also not necessary to make the `match` expression fully qualified. The above will apply to any `<job_information>`, no matter how deeply nested it may be.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and a solution. It is kind of a work around and it will filter all job_information nodes which are irrelevant. But:
1. The condition in xslt in the snippet works for the logic inside the process which filters out all past and future employees.
2. I want to have only active records (with first job_information) and to have it all working properly I need to connect those 2 conditions.
from xslt and from xpath snippet

Comment: I can see that if I will use the same condition which you gave me and add same condition for start_date it should work for me

<xsl:template match="job_information[xs:date(end_date) &gt; current-date() and xs:date(start_date) &lt; current-date()]" />

Comment: That restriction was not defined in your question, but if your data can contain future jobs then obviously it makes sense to filter on `start_date` as well